# How to implement compile time size deduction in std::array<std::string, N> &parameter in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to create a function that in the end should be evaluated at compile time. The problem I'm having is that I'm stuck at passing an initializer list as argument and automatically deduce its size.

I've tried first by creating this object:

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
int main(void)
{
    std::array test = { "Hello"s, "World"s }; // Works perfectly, deduces both std::string type and size
}
```

However if I create a function and pass the initializer list there I'm getting this:

```
template<size_t N>
void Test(std::array<std::string, N> &argument) { }

using namespace std::string_literals;
int main(void)
{
    Test({ "Hello"s, "World"s }); //Error: could not deduce template argument for N
}
```

I thought the compiler should obviously deduce the number of elements in the list and generate the function definition accordingly.
Is my function declaration wrong?
Sorry in advance if this has been asked before, c++ vocabulary is ambiguous...

Comment: `{"Hello"s, "World"s}` isn't a `std::array<std::string, 2>`, it's a `std::initializer_list<std::string>`. And such an initializer list _could_ be used to initialize an `std::array<std::string, 2>`... Or a `std::array<std::string, 3>`, or `4`, etc.

Comment: @NathanPierson: "*it's a `std::initializer_list<std::string>`.*" No, it's not. It's a braced-init-list. It has no type; it's not even an expression.

Comment: Oops, thanks for correcting that misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Braced-init-lists (which is what `{ "Hello"s, "World"s }` is called) do not participate in *function* template argument deduction. The prior code worked because that is *class* template argument deduction, which has special rules that allow the immediate elements of a braced-init-list to be treated as arguments to a hypothetical function.

The simplest alternative is to force the use of CTAD: `Test(std::array{ "Hello"s, "World"s });`. Of course, that won't work anyway since you took the parameter as a non-`const` reference, but that was always going to get you into trouble.

Comment: So.... is there no way to deduce the size of a braced-init-list? Like... I just want to write less code, that is also logical. I thought that's what the STD library was for...

Comment: @CherestesRadu: "*I just want to write less code*" That's not a braced-init-list's primary job. Forcing you to write a typename there in ambiguous circumstances is not an accident.

Comment: It's the same grammar though, I don't want to start dissing C++ so I'll leave it at that. Thanks for clarifying this catastrophe of a language.